# set a custom drawable for all checkboxes in my app

Tags: android, android-styles, android-checkbox

I am trying to set custom backgrounds for all checkboxes.  Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Foo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/MyCheckbox</item>
    </style>
  <style name="MyCheckbox" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
      <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxChecked" /> // unbound prefix error here.
      <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxUnchecked" />
  </style>
</resources>
```

But when I try to build, I get an unbound prefix error on the line for state_checked="true".  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to add a `selector drawable` in the style which will give you compile time error.

**solution:**

You need to create an xml file in your `drawable` as a `selector` and use that xml in your style as a background

**sample:**

create a drawable named `checkbox_selector` in your `drawable folder` or whatever name you want

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxChecked" /> // unbound prefix error here.
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/checkboxUnchecked" />
</selector>
```

use that drawable in your style

```
 <style name="MyCheckbox" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/checkbox_selector</item>
  </style>
```